# Emit message on socket.io from server controller using the chat module implementation

Tags: meanjs

I'm new to mean.js and ran into a problem. I added the chat module to my application and i am trying to use the socket implementation in my own module. My module consists of a web page with information about a device and a rest api that is hit by an android application with updates. What i want is to update the web page information each time the android app issues an update. As such i am connecting to the socket from the angular controller of the web page and waiting for an update message. This works fine as i see the connection being made. My problem is I cant figure out how to get the reference to the io or socket object in the server controller so that i can actually emit the update message. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need it:

```
exports.serverFunction(req, res) {
  var io = req.app.get('socketio');
  io.emit(...);
}
```